# Problema al verificar conexión de internet en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi

tengo implementado el siguiente código, que trabaja perfectamente, abajo del codigó les explico cual es el problema loco que tengo

----------------- MainActivity java ------------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivyReciverListener {

    

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_campeonatos);

        checkInternetConecction();

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void checkInternetConecction() {
        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();

        showSnackBar(isConnected);

        if (!isConnected){
            changeActivity();
        }


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void changeActivity() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, activity_offline.class);
                startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void showSnackBar(boolean isConnected) {
        String message;
        int color;

        if (!isConnected){
            message = "You Are Offline..!!";
            color = Color.WHITE;


        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.RL), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View view = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(color);
        snackbar.show();
        }
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



                final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

                ConnectivityReceiver connectivityReceiver = new ConnectivityReceiver();
                registerReceiver(connectivityReceiver, intentFilter);

                MyApp.getInstance().setConnectivyListner(Campeonatos.this);


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {

        if (!isConnected){
            changeActivity();
        }

        showSnackBar(isConnected);
    }


}
```

------------- ConectivityReceiver java ------------

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static ConnectivyReciverListener connectivyReciverListener;

    public ConnectivityReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = Objects.requireNonNull(cm).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (connectivyReciverListener!=null) {
            connectivyReciverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApp
                .getInstance()
                .getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = Objects.requireNonNull(cm).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetwork!=null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    public interface ConnectivyReciverListener {
        void onNetworkConnectionChanged (boolean isConnected);
    }
}
```

----------------------MyApp java ----------------------------

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private  static  MyApp mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApp getInstance(){
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setConnectivyListner(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivyReciverListener listner){
        ConnectivityReceiver.connectivyReciverListener = listner;
    }
}
```

Como verán uso esos 3 códigos, y trabaja perfectamente, si no hay wifi o Datos, te abre una nueva actividad indicándote que tienes problema con la Internet, hasta acá estamos bien, el problema que tengo, es que si la app esta en segundo plano, y estoy en Whatsapp por ejemplo o cualquier otra aplicación, o jugando y se va la Internet, automáticamente se dispara la actividad que indica que no hay Internet de mi aplicación y se pone la app en primer plano por encima del whatsapp o el juego, osea una locura jajaja, yo necesito que se realice esa verificación solo si el usuario tiene la aplicación abierta, si esta en segundo plano no deseo que realice ninguna verificación de la Internet, como puedo lograr ello. Espero se entienda el problema, de antemano gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: Probablemente el problema es que estás usando un misil para matar un mosquito. Estás usando [`BroadCastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) para una tarea en la que no se requiere su uso. Esta herramienta tiene la capacidad de abrir la App cuando se realiza un evento, que es lo que ocurre de hecho. Si necesitas esa notificación únicamente para cuando la App esté en primer plano debes considerar  hacerlo de otro modo más simple.

Comment: Hola Cedano, gracias por comentar, vale vale, Bien vi un video y me guie de alli, pero por lo visto, no sirve entonces, que me recomiendas, tendras algo que me pudiera orientar.

Comment: Revisa [este artículo de la documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing#java) donde ellos explican un modo óptimo de inspeccionar el estado de la conexión. Parece que de todos modos hay que usar `BroadCastReceiver`, pero se guarda en SharedPreferences el estado de la conexión.

Comment: Vale, ya estoy en ello maquina

Comment: changeActivity() es el método que manda llamar la pantalla de desconexión ?@aAaDesigner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar los métodos `onPause()` y `onResume()`, implementalos y cambia el valor de una variable que determine si tu app esta en foreground (primer plano) o background (segundo plano)

```
private static boolean foreground;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        foreground = false; //Segundo plano.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        foreground = true; //Primer plano.
    }
```

de esta forma cuando revises si no hay conexión revisar también si la app esta en primer plano para permitir enviar el mensaje:

```
 if (!isConnected && foreground ) {
     changeActivity();
 }
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys, gracias por ayudar, te cuento que implemente todo tu codigo e igual sigue sucediendome el problema, apenas quito la conexion, se coloca en primer plano la app, con la activity de que no hay conexion

Comment: Grande Elenasys, si funciona,solo que no lo habia implementado bien, pero listo funciona a la perfeccion.

Comment: Excelente @aAaDesigner saludos!